# li of ul is not centralized with display inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, center

> I'm creating a website with bootstrap and the li's of navigation menu isn't centered. I have tried inline-block, inline with li's and text-align with ul but I don't know where I'm doing wrong. I'm trying this for hours and still stuck in the centering.

The thing is I want my navigation to centralize and as screen size decreases the margin of the ul starts decreasing provided it remains in center of the logo and contact part always.

See Screenshot

[image]

As you can see, I have given a fixed width to the ul and tried to center the li but they just want to be with logo, I don't know why.

ul (.nav) syntax:

```
width: 440px;
text-align: center;
```

li syntax:

```
display: inline;
```

```css
/* MY CSS */

body{
height:4000px;
padding-top:70px;
}
  
.navbar-header img{
float: left;
padding: 10px 10px;
line-height: 20px;
}

.contenta{
margin-top:100px;
}

.navigationary{
margin:40px auto 40px auto;
}

.separator{
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  height: 10px;
  margin: auto 20px auto 20px;
}

.nav{
  width: 440px;
  text-align: center;    
display:inline-block;
}

.navbar-text{
float: right;
margin-top: 0px;
position:relative;
right: 5px;
}

.navbar-brand{
font-size: 21px;
}

.navbar-left{
margin: 0px 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1053px){
.nav{
float: left;
padding: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<!-- MY HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\css\theme\bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\css\custom\styles.css">
 
   </head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid navigationary">
  <!-- Logo -->
  <div class="navbar-header navbar-left">
   <a href="#"><img src="./images/server.png" alt="brand logo" width="50px" height="50px"></a>
   <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">HostKing</a>
  <!-- mobile hamburger navigation -->
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hamburger-linker">
  <span class="sr-only">Navigation Toggle</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  
  </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Simple Link -->
  <div class="navbar-collapse" id="hamburger-linker">
  <div class="navbar-text">
   <p>Do you need help? Just Email, Live Chat or Call Us</p>
   <button>Live Chat</button>
   <span class="separator"></span>
   <span class="numbera">6284-6534</span>
   
  </div>
  <!-- Menu -->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav container-fluid">
   <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a><span class="sr-only">Home page</span></li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">PRICING</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">DOMAIN</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">HOSTING</a></li>
             </ul>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
  
 
  <div class="contenta">
  <div class="col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dictum purus et volutpat semper. Aenean suscipit lectus ornare dictum tempor. Pellentesque mi purus, aliquet id eros id, lobortis pellentesque mauris. Nulla lectus velit, tempor sagittis velit in, maximus laoreet turpis. Maecenas aliquet lacus sed odio porta, at ornare arcu imperdiet. Vestibulum varius sem eu ante ultricies vehicula. Nam sit amet est tempor, volutpat elit elementum, venenatis nibh.</div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dictum purus et volutpat semper. Aenean suscipit lectus ornare dictum tempor. Pellentesque mi purus, aliquet id eros id, lobortis pellentesque mauris. Nulla lectus velit, tempor sagittis velit in, maximus laoreet turpis. Maecenas aliquet lacus sed odio porta, at ornare arcu imperdiet. Vestibulum varius sem eu ante ultricies vehicula. Nam sit amet est tempor, volutpat elit elementum, venenatis nibh.</p></div>
  <p>
  <div class="col-md-6"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dictum purus et volutpat semper. Aenean suscipit lectus ornare dictum tempor. Pellentesque mi purus, aliquet id eros id, lobortis pellentesque mauris. Nulla lectus velit, tempor sagittis velit in, maximus laoreet turpis. Maecenas aliquet lacus sed odio porta, at ornare arcu imperdiet. Vestibulum varius sem eu ante ultricies vehicula. Nam sit amet est tempor, volutpat elit elementum, venenatis nibh.</p></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dictum purus et volutpat semper. Aenean suscipit lectus ornare dictum tempor. Pellentesque mi purus, aliquet id eros id, lobortis pellentesque mauris. Nulla lectus velit, tempor sagittis velit in, maximus laoreet turpis. Maecenas aliquet lacus sed odio porta, at ornare arcu imperdiet. Vestibulum varius sem eu ante ultricies vehicula. Nam sit amet est tempor, volutpat elit elementum, venenatis nibh.</p></div>
  </p>
  <div class="col-md-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer dictum purus et volutpat semper. Aenean suscipit lectus ornare dictum tempor. Pellentesque mi purus, aliquet id eros id, lobortis pellentesque mauris. Nulla lectus velit, tempor sagittis velit in, maximus laoreet turpis. Maecenas aliquet lacus sed odio porta, at ornare arcu imperdiet. Vestibulum varius sem eu ante ultricies vehicula. Nam sit amet est tempor, volutpat elit elementum, venenatis nibh.</div>
  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=".\js\jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your HTML code too, or better yet set up a fiddle for us so we can assist you fully

Comment: I have added the html part.

Comment: Please answer anyone!